# zend resources.frontController.baseUrl don`t work

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, zend-controller-router, zend-config

I need to put one zend project in a subdirectory of my root server. I want my project in: **"http://blog.com/site"** and not in **"http://blog.com"**.
Trying to do it, I`ve added in file: **/application/configs/application.ini** the line below:

`resources.frontController.baseUrl = "http://blog.com/site"`
but when I access "http://blog.com/site" it returns this error:
Invalid controller specified (site)

If I put in bootstrap the line below:

```
$fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
echo $fc->getBaseUrl();
```

it writes **"http://blog.com/site"**

How can I do the subdiretory "/site" do not be consider a controller? because I want it as a part of url.

Answer (score 3):

Add RewriteBase to your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /site
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```